# Programmatically layout buttons

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to Android Development, having much experience in desktop and Web Application coding, and am just getting to grips with how the view layouts work. I have been using Linear Layouts and weights previously to solve my design issues, but due (I believe) to this design not being, uniformly tabular I am struggling.
[image]

I want Tag5 next to Tag0 and under Tag1, and then Tag 6 and 7 next to it.  My code to do this so far is

```
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int width = size.x;
    int height = size.y;

    String tag;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
        int indColumn = width / 7;
        int indColumnHeight = height / 9;
        tag = "#tag" + i;
        View tagView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_child, null, false);
        Button tagTextView = (Button) tagView.findViewById(R.id.tagTextView);
        if (i == 0 || i == 3 || i == 6 || i == 7) {
            tagTextView.setWidth(Math.round(indColumn * 2));
        } else {
            tagTextView.setWidth(Math.round(indColumn));
        }
        if (i == 0) {
            tagTextView.setHeight(Math.round(indColumnHeight * 2));
        } else {
            tagTextView.setHeight(Math.round(indColumnHeight));
        }

        tagTextView.setText(tag);
        tagLayout.addView(tagView);
```

I have tried adding

```
        if(i==5) {
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, 0);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, 1);
            tagTextView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        }
```

before the tagTextView.set Text but it is making no difference

The xml looks like this for an individual button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/tagTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#a000"
    android:textColor="#fff"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: My advise is to create first a static xml with the layout and once you have achieved what you want make it programmatically. What you want to achieve can be done with a `LinearLayout` that define the external table (in terms of html) with 'horizontal' orientation and inner LinearLayout for the rows - every row is a new "table" containing the various buttons. Remember to define the appropriate orientation for the various LinearLayout, between `horizontal` and `vertical`.

Comment: I did try this, but it was complaining about nested Layouts, and I couldn't achieve the screen percentage width in that way.  This code is based on an article about achieving screen percentage widths. I don't even really want it programmatic it just seemed to be the only way I could half achieve what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

I took what EasyJoin Dev said, and tweaked it a little, I created a Relative layout using the layout_toEndOf and layout_below options, and then in the activities create method I overrode the width and height programmatically to get my percentage based sizing.

Comment: If it works for you it's fine. With LinearLayout you can also "play" with the `weight` attribute to give more or less width to the cells - or even set a cell to fill all the available width.